# error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

Tags: c++, vector

```
template <typename Z> Z myTemplate <Z> :: popFromVector ()
{
    if (myVector.empty () == false)
        return myVector.pop_back ();

    return 0;
}

int main ()
{
    myTemplate <int> obj;

    std :: cout << obj.popFromVector();

    return 0;
}
```

Error:

```
error: void value not ignored as it ought to be
```

AFAI can see, the return type of `popFromVector` is NOT void. What's the point that I am missing?
The error disappears when I comment out this call in main().

Comment: Are you sure that's the error message from the compiler? What compiler are you using?

Comment: The return value of `std::vector<>::pop_back` is however `void`. You want something like `{Z x=myVector.back(); myVector.pop_back(); return x; }` instead.

Comment: What is `myVector`? What is the line with error?

Comment: @user786653 That was helpful, thanks. If you post that as an answer, I'll accept that.

Comment: @user786653 Now since you haven't responded...

Answer (score 17, accepted):

`std::vector<T>::pop_back()` returns void. You attempt to return it as an int. This is not allowed.

Comment: If we knew that the OP was using `std::vector` internally that'd be the answer...

Comment: @DeadMG Ah I never noticed that. Thanks much.

Comment: Would you care to explain? Your response is of no use to people that don't know how to fix the problem. I mean not to be offensive only helpful. I don't know how to use templates very well. In fact I just learned about them. Please build off of your three sentences.

Comment: @dylnmc: This answer is perfectly clear. There is no way to tell you "how to fix the problem" in general because it depends on what you're trying to do and how you want to design your program. Independent thought required; we can't do _everything_ for you.

Answer (score 9):

That is because the definition of `std::vector::pop_back` has a `void` return type ... you are trying to return something from that method, which won't work since that method doesn't return anything.

Change your function to the following so you can return what's there, and remove the back of the vector as well:

```
template <typename Z> Z myTemplate <Z> :: popFromVector ()
{
    //create a default Z-type object ... this should be a value you can easily
    //recognize as a default null-type, such as 0, etc. depending on the type
    Z temp = Z(); 

    if (myVector.empty () == false)
    {
        temp = myVector.back();
        myVector.pop_back();
        return temp;
    }

    //don't return 0 since you can end-up with a template that 
    //has a non-integral type that won't work for the template return type
    return temp; 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's the `pop_back()`. It has a void return type. You have to use `back()` to get the actual value. This is to avoid unnecessary copies.