# Why am I getting "void value not ignored as it ought to be"?

Tags: c

I have the following function :

```
void getdata(int arr[], int n)
{

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) 
    {
        int a = srand(time(NULL));
        arr[i] = a;
    }
}
```

And I call it in `main`:

```
getdata(arr, 1024);
```

I get "void value not ignored as it ought to be" but I don't understand what is wrong.Why do I get this error?

Comment: don't initialize the PRNG over and over again. Once per program run is enough.

Comment: How is arr declared?  What error do you get?  What void value are you talking about?

Comment: Are you doing something like `x = getdata(arr,1024)` ?

Comment: You are missing a semi-colon. Please prefer to copy/paste your code rather than typing it anew.

Comment: NOTE : If you are trying to to pass arr as a VLA (variable length array) you need to declare `void getdata(int n, int arr[n]) {...}`

Answer (score 36):

```
  int a = srand(time(NULL));
```

The prototype for `srand` is `void srand(unsigned int)` (provided you included `<stdlib.h>`).
This means it returns nothing ... but you're using the value it returns (???) to assign, by initialization, to `a`.

---

*Edit: this is what you need to do:*

```
#include <stdlib.h> /* srand(), rand() */
#include <time.h>   /* time() */

#define ARRAY_SIZE 1024

void getdata(int arr[], int n)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = rand();
    }
}

int main(void)
{
    int arr[ARRAY_SIZE];
    srand(time(0));
    getdata(arr, ARRAY_SIZE);
    /* ... */
}
```

Comment: how can i assign arr[i] = srand(time(NULL))

Comment: srand(time(NULL)) arr[i] = rand() % 100 what is the srand function here?

Comment: @mertmetin `rand` returns a random integer in [0,RAND_MAX]. `srand` just initializes the random number generator. This generator is everything else than random (it's actually a pseudo-radom number genrator). With `srand` you initialize it to some seed value. For the same seed value the following calls to `rand` will give the same sequence of numbers. So calling `srand` once at startup (or before calling `getdata` with some more-or-less random value (in this case based on current time) makes the following `rand` calls different each time your program runs.

Comment: @mertmetin But calling `srand` each time before `rand` is a bad idea, as for the same value passed to `srand`, `rand` will return the same value. Although you bring in the current time here, this is still a bad idea. Read the links in my comment to the other answer to gain more insight into this matter.

Comment: `void value not ignored as it ought to be`: why such cryptic error message? Why not simply `void value cannot be assigned to non-void variable`?

Comment: QOI (*Quality Of Implementation*) @pmor. With this implementation the error message for `sqrt(srand(time(0)))` can be the same as for `a = srand(time(0))`.

Answer (score 33):

*The original poster is quoting a GCC compiler error message, but even by reading this thread, it's not clear that the error message is properly addressed - except by [@pmg's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8896340/1177073). (+1, btw)*

---

## error: void value not ignored as it ought to be

This is a GCC error message that means the return-value of a function is 'void', but that you are trying to assign it to a non-void variable.

Example:

```
void myFunction()
{
   //...stuff...
}

int main()
{
   int myInt = myFunction(); //Compile error!

    return 0;
}
```

You aren't allowed to assign void to integers, or any other type.

In the OP's situation:

```
int a = srand(time(NULL));
```

...is not allowed. `srand()`, [according to the documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/srand/?kw=srand), returns **void**.

**This question is a duplicate of:**

- [error: void value not ignored as it ought to be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7307830/error-void-value-not-ignored-as-it-ought-to-be)
- ["void value not ignored as it ought to be" - Qt/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14109774/void-value-not-ignored-as-it-ought-to-be-qt-c)
- [GCC C compile error, void value not ignored as it ought to be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7534880/gcc-c-compile-error-void-value-not-ignored-as-it-ought-to-be)

*I am responding, despite it being duplicates, because this is the top result on Google for this error message. Because this thread is the top result, it's important that this thread gives a succinct, clear, and easily findable result.*

Answer (score 11):

`srand` doesn't return anything so you can't initialize `a` with its return value because, well, because it doesn't return a value. Did you mean to call `rand` as well?

Comment: @mertmetin So then don't call [`srand`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/srand/) but [`rand`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/rand/)! got it?

Answer (score 5):

```
    int a = srand(time(NULL))
        arr[i] = a;
```

Should be

```
        arr[i] = rand();
```

And put `srand(time(NULL))` somewhere at the very beginning of your program.

Answer (score 4):

"void value not ignored as it ought to be" 
 this error occurs when function like srand(time(NULL)) does not return something and you are treating it as it is returning something. As in case of pop() function in queue ,if you will store the popped element in a variable you will get the same error because it does not return anything.