# "void value not ignored as it ought to be" - Qt/C++

Tags: c++, qt, casting, void

I have this simple "interface" for some plugins I want to develop, it looks like:

```
class TestPluginBase : public QObject
{
  Q_OBJECT
public:
    TestPluginBase();
    qint64 returnType(){return PluginType;}

protected:
    qint64 PluginType;
};
```

And some other classes which implement the "interface" like:

```
class TestPluginONE : public TestPluginBase
{
public:
    TestPluginONE() {this->PluginType =1;}
    qint64 returnType() {return this->PluginType;}
};
```

Then I have another function which suppose to load different plugins:

```
qint64 TestPluginManager::loadPlugin(QObject *_plugin)
{

  TestPluginBase *Plugin = qobject_cast<TestPluginBase *>(_plugin);

  if ( !Plugin )
        return 0;

    emit sigPluginLoaded(Plugin);
    return Plugin->returnType();

}
```

But when building it I get `void value not ignored as it ought to be` and Qt creator says instantiated from the line I'm doing my cast... can't figure out what I'm doing wrong...any help/hint is appreciated.

Comment: Where is `sigPluginLoaded` defined?

Comment: in the same header file that `loadPlugin` function is defined. Even If I comment it out, I get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

modified the constructor in my "interface" to `TestPluginBase() {this->PluginType =0;}` and the code is compiling with no error..solved my problem but don't know why.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem by going back to the previous code ?

Comment: Weird enough Now when i compile the previous code I get many of `TestPluginONE.cpp:-1: error: undefined reference to TestPluginBase::TestPluginBase()' `