Can someone solve my "void value not ignored as it ought to be" error?
I am getting the error:

void value not ignored as it ought to be

Can someone please help me solve this (I'm not a pro Arduino coder)?
When I compile it, I get the error on line 79:
done = radio.read( received_data, num_received_data );

I don't know how to solve it, or even what is happening here.
#include <Servo.h> 
#include <SPI.h>
#include "nRF24L01.h"
#include "RF24.h"
#include "printf.h"

RF24 radio(9,10);

Servo CH1;  
Servo CH2; 
Servo CH3;  
Servo CH4;  
Servo CH5;  
Servo CH6; 
int ch1; 
int ch2;
int ch3;
int ch4;
int ch5;
int ch6;
const int CH7 =  4;  
const int CH8 =  3;  
const int CH9 =  5;  
const int CH10 =  2;  
const int SIGNAL =  7;  
const uint64_t pipe = 0xE8E8F0F0E1LL;
uint8_t received_data[12];
uint8_t num_received_data =sizeof(received_data);
void setup(void)
{
delay(3000);  

CH1.attach(15); //right-y(AIL)
CH2.attach(16); //right-x(ELE)  
CH3.attach(19); //vol-batt (CH6)
CH4.attach(18); //left-x  (CH5)
CH5.attach(17); //left-y (RUD)
CH6.attach(14); //throt

pinMode(CH7, OUTPUT);
pinMode(CH8, OUTPUT);
pinMode(CH9, OUTPUT);
pinMode(CH10, OUTPUT);
pinMode(SIGNAL, OUTPUT);
Serial.begin(57600);
printf_begin();
printf("\n\rRF24/Reciever/\n\r");


  radio.begin();
  radio.openReadingPipe(1,pipe);
  radio.startListening();
  radio.printDetails(); 
}


void loop(void)
{
  
  
  

  if ( radio.available() )
  {
  digitalWrite(SIGNAL, HIGH) ;     
  }
  else {
  digitalWrite(SIGNAL, LOW) ; 
  }     

    bool done = false;
    int ESC_value;
    while (!done)
    
    {
 
      
      done = radio.read( received_data, num_received_data );

//////////////PWM//////////////
ch1=(received_data[1]); 
ch1=ch1+3;
CH1.write(ch1); 

ch2=(received_data[2]);
ch2=ch2+4;
CH2.write(ch2); 

ch3=(received_data[3]); 
ch3=ch3+4;
CH3.write(ch3);

ch4=(received_data[4]); 
ch4=ch4+4;
CH4.write(ch4); 
 
ch5=(received_data[5]); 
ch5=ch5+4;
CH5.write(ch5); 

ch6=(received_data[6]); 
ch6=ch6+4;
CH6.write(ch6); 
 
//////////////0-1//////////////
if ((received_data[7])>100) {
    digitalWrite(CH7, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(CH7, LOW);
  } 

 //////////////   
if ((received_data[8])>100) {
    digitalWrite(CH8, HIGH);
  }
  else {
    digitalWrite(CH8, LOW);
  }  


printf("\n\r");
Serial.print("ROL:");Serial.print(radio.available()); Serial.print("\t");
Serial.print("PITCH:");Serial.print((received_data[2])); Serial.print("\t");
Serial.print("THROT:");Serial.print((received_data[1])); Serial.print("\t");
    }
  }

I will upload it on an atmega328p for my DIY RC controller.

Please try to create a [mre] to show us, with emphasis on the minimal part. And please copy-paste the full and complete build-log into the question (as text). Also please add a comment on the line in the code where you get the error.

can some one solve my "void value not ignored as it ought to be" error? Yes. But that's not a particularly useful answer so you should consider rephrasing.

Sorry, I gave up reading after all those globals. Are they really essential to showing what the problem is?

On a different note (unrelated to your problem) but you should not have a loop doing work in the loop function. It's named loop because the Arduino system calls it in a loop, so you should not have a loop yourself. If you have a loop, then that will block the Arduino system from working correctly.

As the error mentions, RF24::read returns void.  Assigning that void to a bool done; has no meaning.

radio.read() is a void function. It does not return anything so you cannot assign it's non-existant return value to the done variable. Now the question is how do you end your while loop instead, I'm afraid I don't know the answer to that.

read is a void function. It doesn't return anything.

Tactical note: When you have a series of sequentially named-or-numbered variables the code will most likely be a lot easier to write if they are aggregated into an array.

Voted to close this as a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8896281/why-am-i-getting-void-value-not-ignored-as-it-ought-to-be It's about C but the solution answer is the same.

" I get the error on line 79:" -- This tells you how to create a minimal example. Start with line 79 and add just what you need to make it almost-compile aside from the error you're asking about. Something more like #include "RF24.h"
RF24 radio(9,10); uint8_t received_data[12]; uint8_t num_received_data =sizeof(received_data); void loop(void) { bool done = false; done = radio.read( received_data, num_received_data ); }. Trash your functionality; keep your error.

Per the documentation, the RF24::read() method returns void, ie it doesn't return anything. So you can't assign the return value to your done variable.
